# Force to save draft (answer and question)

Tags: support, drafts

I sometimes ask a/multiple question(s) as comment(s) to a question and at the same time, I prepare an answer if the OP answers in a certain way but without posting before they answer.

Each time I want to save my draft, I need to wait quite a long time (it's variable, but still too long). I want to save it instantly by clicking a button or performing an action (keyboard shortcut...).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's impossible; drafts are saved with an HTTP call to the server, like this:

[image]

and it's possible to mimic that call and have your draft saved the moment you want it. It would even be feasible to [write a userscript that does this](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script-request).

But there's no 'standard' way to do it, and to be honest, I'm not sure it's very useful. Drafts are deleted after seven days, and I usually save my drafts in the standard Notes app, or as a .md file on my computer or in [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/) if I need the formatting.

Another option would be to continue browsing in another tab or window, and let the site save the draft in the background.